# Integrating Civicrm in Laravel Package

Tags: api, integration

I have been learning Civicrm for something now. Now that I am familiar with the whole idea, I would like to integrate Civicrm in Laravel package.

I understand its not going to be an easy task, that's why I need your input, suggestions and a point to the right direction.

What should I really focus on? Should I simply create an API wrapper that interacts with the database with a fancy theme?

What steps should I take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much at all about Laravel, but from this:

> one conclusion I would draw from that is that Laravel is probably best to use as a front-end framework, which does not require complex data store functionality. It is perfectly suited to be a service layer with its integration to Iron.io and other popular SaaS providers (AWS, S3, sendgrid, etc.), Laravel provides a simple way to build and consume API’s [THE GREAT PHP MVC FRAMEWORK SHOWDOWN OF 2016](http://zenofcoding.com/2015/11/16/the-great-php-mvc-framework-showdown-of-2016-cakephp-3-vs-symfony-2-vs-laravel-5-vs-zend-2/)

I would suggest starting by creating a wrapper for CiviCRM's extensive API. Version 3 is quite mature, version 4 is a new initiative that will eliminate some of the cruft that has developed in v3 but isn't yet covering as much as v3. FWIW, CiviCRM 5.0 is going to more thoroughly integrate various parts of Symfony 2, and we're aspiring to support progressive decoupling / headless sites that are implemented using a browser based MVC like Angular.

Comment: This reminds me of the well known Microsoft business model. The developers have no time to fix all the current bugs because they are busy on the next version. Hope I am wrong about this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Paul. As a community we work to address both current bugs and move the project forward by supporting new technologies, replacing deprecated libraries, and where possible replacing crufty old code built here with externally maintained libraries/projects with equivalent or better functionality. Sure @Digitlimit's intent to expose CiviCRM functionality through laravel is a long-shot exploration in terms of something that will get lots of traction in the community. But heh, it might potentially lead to a breakthrough and not just incremental improvements.

Comment: Sorry, I am just in shock that we lost CiviMail bulk mail and ACLs when 'upgrading' to 4.7.x. It's such a huge project it must be impossible to regression test everything.

Comment: @Joe Murray Thanks for taking your time to respond and for your detailed suggestion. Actually Laravel is 100% backend Framework and has attracted many developers since its first release. I will consider the option of creating an API wrapper, this is to avoid breaking or re-inventing Civicrm functionalities. When will CiviCRM 5.0 be released?Looks more like what I need since Laravel plays nicely with Symfony and most of Laravel's features are from Symfony

Comment: CiviCRM is already using some Symfony. I'm not sure there is a definite date for 5.0 release. Perhaps fall 2016?

Answer (score 2):

I have published a quick Laravel package that can help building the API3 integration... it also has a lot of documentation that is not easy to find in the Civi world...

Take a look... contribute...

https://github.com/leanwebstart/civi-api3

Also on pakagist... leanwebstart/civi-api3

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: quite impressive. Nice start. Nice work.